# Which essential packages I should install in TeXLive on Windows?

Tags: texlive, windows

Which essential packages I should install for home use of LaTeX (TeXLive) on Windows?

Comment: Better to install the full version and avoid future headaches,

Comment: Define _essential_! More seriously, this is really not a question with an answer: it very much depends on how you use TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the full version of texlive and write your document. If it is a LaTeX file, you can use `\listfiles` at the very beginning.

Compile the document and open the log. Delete everything in your installation below `/texmf-dist` which is not listed in the log.

Renew the database (`texhash`) and you are mostly done.

Comment: Do i have to install TexWorks? My favourite text editor is Atom.

Comment: An editor is not essential. You can write your code on the command line.